# Context Menu not getting minimised

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have a page that is being hosted in a window. The page has an ultragrid in which there is a context menu. When the context menu is opened, and the window is minimised using windows+m, the window gets minimized but the context menu is not getting minimized.

The window gets minimised to the taskbar but the context menu is still visible.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: This is not standard behavior from WPF at least not when running on WinXP. What is an ultragrid? Is it causing this? Try with a context menu on a regular WPF control, do you still have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The context menu is a floating element, it's not part of the window. In my view, it makes sense that it is still visible.

What I would recommend is to detect the window being minimized and automatically get rid of it if it exists... Using a StateChanged event on Window.

Comment: How do i do that...i mean hw do i minimise the context menu using the window state changed event....